# PHP Xpath check if node exist

Tags: php, xpath

I've an XML ( $fileXML ) like:

```
<FatturaElettronicaHeader>
   <CedentePrestatore>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>MY STORE SRL</Denominazione>
          <Cognome>Rossi</Cognome>
        </Anagrafica>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
   </CedentePrestatore>
</FatturaElettronicaHeader>
```

I use this function to retrieve some values:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($fileXML);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);            
$nodes = $xpath->query('//CedentePrestatore/DatiAnagrafici');
foreach ($nodes as $nodelist) {

  $denominazione = $xpath->query( 'Anagrafica/Denominazione', $nodelist)->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $cognome = $xpath->query( 'Anagrafica/Cognome', $nodelist)->item(0)->nodeValue;

}
```

It work great. But node `Cognome` is optional in the XML, so sometimes it doesn't exist, like:

```
<FatturaElettronicaHeader>
   <CedentePrestatore>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>MY SHOP2 SRL</Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
   </CedentePrestatore>
</FatturaElettronicaHeader>
```

Then my script get error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

How can I modify my code to assign at variable `$cognome` node value if exist, empty string `""` in other cases?

Comment: Which of these lines shows the problem? Why not check whether an object is returned by any of these method calls or not?

Comment: $cognome = $xpath->query( 'Anagrafica/Cognome', $nodelist)->item(0)->nodeValue; when use the second XML example, where Cognome is not present

Comment: And why not check whether `$xpath->query( 'Anagrafica/Cognome', $nodelist)->item(0)` is an object or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chech that xpath returns any node

```
$cognome = $xpath->query( 'Anagrafica/Cognome', $nodelist);
$cognome = $cognome->length ? $cognome->item(0)->nodeValue : '';
```